# Jar with compressed music with java?

Tags: java, jar, mp3, jlayer

I've tried to add music to an application I've made. First I tried with `.wav` files though they became so huge that the application became too large to upload anywhere.

So I changed the files to `.mp3`, tried `JMF` and `JLayer` though both of them won't work on runnable jars (even if they work fine when I haven't exported them).

So anyone got any tips on how to play compressed music with a runnable jar?

Here's the code for JLayer, when exported it stops working at `f = new File(u.toURI())` without throwing any exceptions...

```
try {

    URL u = cl.getResource("New Beginnings.mp3");
    f = new File(u.toURI());

} catch (URISyntaxException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}

try {

    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
    p = new Player(fis);
    p.play();

} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

Edit: Fixed with changing the above code to:

```
try {

      InputStream fis = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(temp+".mp3");
      p = new Player(fis);
      p.play();

   } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println(e);
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Where did you place the sound file exactly?

You should create a new package inside your project and place the resources there, then read the file by sending a complete path:

ex. create a new package called sounds, then:

```
  InputStream fis = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/sounds/"+temp+".mp3");
  p = new Player(fis);
  p.play();
```

To be honest, I didn't try it with sounds, but this problem happened to me when I used images. I placed them in a package, and everything worked fine..

Comment: You don't have to create a new package inside your project, just place it within the src and it should be fine. As mentioned I fixed it when I changed the code, I had forgotten that creating a new File in a jar isn't allowed. :o

Comment: @Skarion How to play if the mp3 files are outside of the jar ?? My Application is a kind of music player.

Comment: @Skarion jFileOpener or whatever it is called, get the URL, and send it to the player.