# Playing an MP3 in a jar with mp3spi

Tags: java, audio, jar

I'm working on a Java project in Eclipse IDE. I want to deploy the project into a jar-file. Getting the audio to run is the part I have diffictuly with. I'm using the mp3spi library by javazoom for playing mp3 files. ( http://www.javazoom.net/mp3spi/sources.html )

I implemented my AudioPlayer almost like the **sample on the javazoom website. ( http://www.javazoom.net/mp3spi/documents.html )**

I could post the lengthy code here again, but it's almost the same with the difference that my AudioPlayer extends Thread so it can play independently. (and it works just fine in the development environment)

The problem I have is that I just can't get it to run when I export the project into a jar. I found already many questions and suggestions to this topic and I tried most of it. Sadly I still don't have a working solution. I'm sure it's out there but at this point I might miss the forest for the trees.

All the required libraries (jl1.0.1.jar, tritonus_share.jar and mp3spi1.9.5.jar) are in my jar and added to the classpath.

The curcial point of the code seems to be AudioInputStream (at line 10 in the sample) which takes a File to be created.

**1st attempt** - the code like suggested on javazoom.net:

```
File file = new File("src/resources/audio/test.mp3");
AudioInputStream ain = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
```

What happens is:

Eclipse IDE:
Works fine, the mp3 plays.

Exported jar-File:
Jar works but mp3 does not play.

Exported jar-File opend with windows console:
Jar works but mp3 does not play.

> Error messages: at audio.AudioPlayer.run(AudioPlayer.java:40)
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: src\resources\audio\test.mp3

So I can't use „File“ in a jar because I'm not dealing with a file in the file system but a file inside my jar.

**2nd attempt**

```
URL url = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("resources/audio/test.mp3");
AudioInputStream ain = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url);
```

What happens is:

Eclipse IDE:
Works fine, the mp3 plays.

Exported jar-File:
Jar works but mp3 does not play.

Exported jar-File opend with windows console:
Jar works but mp3 does not play.

> Error messages: javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException:
>   could not get audio input stream from input URL
>           at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(Unknown Source)
>           at audio.AudioPlayer.run(AudioPlayer.java:40)

I can't get an AudioInputStream from a URL? I don't know. So let's get to ...

**3rd and 4th attempt**

Attempt 3:

```
BufferedInputStream myStream = new BufferedInputStream(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resources/audio/test.mp3"));
AudioInputStream ain = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(myStream);
```

Attempt 4:

```
BufferedInputStream myStream = new BufferedInputStream(ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("resources/audio/test.mp3"));
AudioInputStream ain = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(myStream);
```

Again both with the result playing in Eclipse IDE but not in the jar.

Exported jar-File opend with windows console:
Jar works but mp3 does not play.

> Error messages: javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException:
>   could not get audio input stream from input stream
>           at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(Unknown Source)
>           at audio.AudioPlayer.run(AudioPlayer.java:40)

I am really lost here. Any help would be much appreciated.

Related topics:

[File path or file location for Java - new file()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16313260/file-path-or-file-location-for-java-new-file)

[Reading File In JAR using Relative Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5054435/reading-file-in-jar-using-relative-path)

[Java Audio Stream (mp3spi lib), UnsupportedAudioFileException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12032663/java-audio-stream-mp3spi-lib-unsupportedaudiofileexception)

[Jar with compressed music with java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4942866/jar-with-compressed-music-with-java)

Answer (score 0):

I used to export my project always as a jar and all images that I loaded in a similar manner would load properly while the audio file would not.

Now, that I tried to export my project as a runnable jar, it works just fine (attempt 4, maybe other attempts as well). The following question and answer explains the difference between jar and runnable jar.

[Java Eclipse: Difference between exporting as a JAR and exporting as a Runnable JAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4974693/java-eclipse-difference-between-exporting-as-a-jar-and-exporting-as-a-runnable)

How that manifest file impacts the proper loading of resources with

```
ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream
```

is beyond me, but apparently it does.

Somebody might want to elaborate on those maifest files because I really can't. Or perhaps there are other differences between the export of a jar and a runnable jar.

Since I have a working solution I am done for now with this subject.